# Rails 3 radio button; saving multiple attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am having trouble saving multiple values with a radio button. I have two models, result and question. Question has_many results/results belongs_to questions. In my results controller I am doing:

```
def new
@questions = Question.all
for question in @questions
@result = Result.new
question.results.build
end
```

In my view I have...

```
<table>
<% for question in @questions %>
<tr>
<td><%= question.name %><p></td>
<%=  0.upto(4) do |value| %>
<td> <%= f.radio_button :score, value, :index => question.id %></td>
<% end %>
</tr>
</tr>
<% end %>
</table>
```

When I submit this page I get an attribute error, and paramters that look like...

Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"OGIsyXc7myrK1SIl/auvI57Rghriw3Uh566mJTbZO4Q=", "result"=>{"1"=>{"score"=>"0"}, "2"=>{"score"=>"1"}, "3"=>{"score"=>"2"}}, "commit"=>"Create Result"}

Result has two fields :score and :question_id. I want to save both those fields for each question. So think I need parameters that look like: "result"=>{"question_id"=>"1""score"=>"0"}..ect.

I would appreciate any help!

I have cloned the app here: https://github.com/marklocklear/survey_test

If someone would be willing to clone the repo and take a look at the app that would be awesome. I added a few notes to the readme.

Comment: it sounds as though checkboxes would be a better way to go here

Answer (score 0):

Check your associations, if it is a one to many association it would be something like

question.rb

```
has_many :results
```

result.rb

```
belongs_to :question  #(not questions)
```

Don't know about your controller, but it should be something like:

```
def new
@questions = Question.all
@result=@questions.build_result
end
```

For the view, maybe check nested forms.
http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1